# Bash multiplication with printf command

Tags: bash

I am wondering why the following code not work. Could you please give me suggestion?

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0; i<=20; i++))
do  
    printf "%.2f" "0.05 * $i";
done
```

Comment: How do you suspect that's correct Bash syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`printf "%.2f" "3 * 4"` does not work because `"3 * 4"` is not a number. It's literally just that string. Neither `bash` nor `printf` interpret your string as an expression whose value has to be computed. `printf` hasn't that ability to begin with.

To compute things in `bash` you can use `(( var = ... ))` or `$(( ... ))`. However, `bash` can only handle integers but no floating point numbers.

So in your case you have to resort to external programs like `dc` or `bc`. You may also delimit the printed numbers by a space or newline:

```
for ((i=0; i<=20; i++))
do  
    printf '%.2f\n' "$(bc <<< "0.05 * $i")"
done
```